# Json parse to c# object

Tags: c#, json, firebase

Hi everyone i tried parse json object to c# object. I have this json:

```
{
  "etcacik": {
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "etcacikmenusu",
    "Values": {
      "cacik": {
        "Id": 2,
        "Price": 2
      },
      "et": {
        "Id": 1,
        "Price": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And my classes about this object :

```
public class MenuItem
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<MenuSubItem> Values { get; set; }
}
public class MenuSubItem
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Price")]
    public string Price { get; set; }
}
```

My code in the Processing Service:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("Menu.json?auth=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX").Result;
var JSON= response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MenuItem>(JSON);
```

What I want to do is openly show json string contained objects in a list and perform CRUD operations on them.
But since I do not show these objects as a list, I need to show them in the sub items.
But I get an error when I do not list the incoming json string like I wanted.

Edited with Feedbacks:

```
public class MenuItem
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, MenuSubItem> Values;
}
public class MenuSubItem
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Price { get; set; }
}
```

to:

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, MenuItem>>(jsonString);
```

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Please clear up the last part a little bit and also use English words to give us a context.

Comment: Your model does not match with the json data. Values in json is an object, not array. So you need to remove Name Property from MenuSubItem and change Values property to Dictionary<string, MenuSubItem> in MenuItem class, where the key is the name of menu sub item, and value is nested data.

Comment: What I want to do is openly Show json string contained objects in a list and perform CRUD operations on them. But since I do not show these objects as a list, I need to show them in the sub items. But I get an error when I do not list the incoming json string like I wanted

Comment: If your json properties were lowerCamelCase you wouldn't need to explicitly set their name

Comment: @RubenVardanyan oh okey i changed that. But now return null i think problem is here ? : 
 var jsonString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MenuItem>(jsonString);

Comment: there should be `var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, MenuItem>>(jsonString);` instead of `var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MenuItem>(jsonString);` where the key of the dictionary is menu item name (in this case _etcacik_) and the value is the menu item

Comment: Thanks for helping it fixed :) @RubenVardanyan